# When the question has been deleted during review, not displaying error

Tags: bug, review

When reviewing first posts, sometimes the question gets deleted while you are reviewing it.  It would be nice if, instead of displaying a blank page with an error message (`This question has been deleted`), the regular review interface would display and it would be possible to move on to the next question without typing in the Stack Overflow URL again.

Comment: Do you remember when/how this error message appeared? That error message doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: @Emmett It appeared as I was reviewing a first post.  For some reason (which I don't remember), I hit the reload button.  Instead of the familiar review interface, a page completely devoid of all formatting showed up with just the text "This question has been deleted."  (Sounds like a SO creepypasta - WHO WAS QUESTION - but it's not.)